# Autocomplete wont work in dynamic added rows using datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have added autocomplete feature in my textbox but I click Add button then new row added but autocomplete wont work. below is my code.

```
$(function() {
$("#skills").autocomplete({
source: 'textbox_auto_complete.php'
});
});

//Add Script

$('#product_table').DataTable();
$(document).on("click","#addRow",function(){ 
var table = $('#product_table').DataTable();
table.row.add(['','','']).draw();
});




<table id="product_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th align="Center">Product Name</th>
<th align="Center">Quantity</th>
<th align="Center">Click Me</th>
</tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input class="product_text skills" type="text" placeholder="Type Product Name" name="skills" id="skills" required="">
</td>
<span id="product_list"></span> 
<td><input class="product_text" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="Quantity" required=""></td>
<td><input class="product_text" type="button" id="addRow" name="addRow" value="Add"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

when i run the code first text field proper run with autocomplete but dynamic row does not work, please find where is problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `id` as selector & `id` is unique. There should be only one `id` in whole page. So it wont applied to other element who have same id other than first. If your input have same `class` you can use that as `class` selector:

```
$(function() {
  $('#product_table').find('.skills').autocomplete({ 
     source: 'textbox_auto_complete.php'
  });
});
```

Comment: do you have same class for that input

Comment: yes sir, i have a same class for input
  table.row.add(['<input class="product_text skills" type="text" placeholder="Type Product Name" name="skills" id="skills" required="">'])